# Avoid re-consumption with Apache Kafka MirrorMaker 2 in an active-active configuration?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running Apache MirrorMaker 2.7 on multiple active Kafka (2.6) clusters (named `prod1`, `prod2`). So `topic` on `prod1` is replicated by MirrorMaker2 as `prod1.topic` on the `prod2` cluster.

I have a Kafka Consumer service running on both `prod1` and `prod2` using the same kafka consumer group-id.

I have `emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds=1` in my MirrorMaker2 config, resulting in offsets being translated every second from
`topic` to `prod1.topic`.

The problem is, everytime my producer produces to `topic` on `prod1`, the data is replicated over to `prod1.topic` on `prod2`, and consumed by my consumer on `prod2` BEFORE the latest-commit offset from my `prod1` consumer is translated over to `prod2` by MirrorMaker2.

This does not happen if I start my `prod2` consumer a few seconds after data is produced to `prod1`, as latest-commit offsets would have arrived on `prod2` by then, however, both my consumers on `prod1/2` need to be running live as I am using `prod1/2` as an active-active deployment configuration.

So how could I ensure any data produced is consumed only once, by either of the `prod1`/ `prod2` consumers?

Answer (score 0):

I been trying to achieve a similar setup for an application running in 2 datacenters, regretfully, looks like for the moment MM2 does not guarantee exactly one consumption, as messages and corresponding offsets are not replicated at the same time

You can decrease the offset commit interval with this setting:
`emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds=1`

Here is some reference about this: https://ibm-cloud-architecture.github.io/refarch-eda/technology/kafka-mirrormaker/#replication-considerations

> Exactly-once delivery is difficult to achieve in distributed system.
> In the case of Kafka, producer, brokers, and consumers are working
> together to ensure only one message is processed end to end. With
> coding practice and configuration settings, within a unique cluster,
> Kafka can guarantee exactly once processing. No duplicated records
> between producer and broker, and committed reads, on consumer side,
> are not reprocessed in case of consumer restarts.
>
> But for cross cluster replications, the semantic is based on at least
> once approach. Duplicates can happen when the mirror maker source task
> stops before committing its offset to the source topic. A restart will
> load records from the last committed offset which can generate
> duplicates.

The duplicate handling should be done by the application.
You could use different consumer groups ids, or configure your app connected to the destination not to consume from the replicated topics and in case source goes down reconfigure your app to start consuming from those too (or deploy an instance that consumes the remaining messages in those topics).